# Text-Align center not working in Footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've created a Website and the footer is fine and everything but when it becomes and smaller screen the writing at the bottom doesn't align center. Now I've tried display: inline-block; and text-align: center; and neither of these work.

Any help I am grateful for :)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    footer p{
        display: inline;
    }
}

footer {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

footer .container {
    font-size: 18px;
}

footer .container p{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

footer .container a{
    color: #8F8;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="pull-left copyright text-muted">&copy; 2015 AAA Oven Cleaning</p>
                <p class="pull-right text-muted">Created By 
                                <a href="#">Crafted-Website</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Image link (This is what's happening): http://gyazo.com/419bc4a2bfda59139de9ef3440f74e18

I have solved this now, all I had to do was

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    footer div {
        display: inline-block!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: `text-align: center` works perfectly.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't

Comment: Then there must be a conflict with some other code. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See that is what I thought but I can't find nothing in the file that would do that accept the pull-left and pull-right but even then in the @media screen when I text-align: center I did !important but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center the text then use:

```
footer .container {
     font-size: 18px;
     text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method, this also doesn't work the text just stays away from each other.

Answer (score 0):

The parent element has to have text-align: center

for example, in your media query for mobile, give footer the following:
    footer {
      text-align: center;
    }

Comment: Done that but that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/jazztorbs/gyxmaz0x/

Comment: Maybe my code somewhere is stopping this from happening but this is what I see: http://gyazo.com/cfa4c5cb95ff81c497293a9f4beb165b

Comment: I pull the text left for on and right for the other and this seems to mess the writing up when on a small screen